# What is the time complexity of these nested for loops?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given some array of numbers i.e. [5,11,13,26,2,5,1,9,...]

What is the time complexity of these loops? The first loop is O(n), but what is the second loop? It iterates the number of times specified at each index in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nums[i]; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `i < nums[i]` ? typo? -> `j < nums[i]` ? as written the inner loop will either have 0 or infinite iterations

Comment: Call it `O(NK)` where `K` is the average of the array?

Comment: as you use `nums[i]` the complexity is undefined as might have an array like `[5,1000000,10000000,10000000,....]`

Comment: big O time complexity is always a matter of perspective. If you regard the elements values average as a constant or bounded by some constant (which it definitely is) then the total complexity is `O(nums.size)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes that is a typo, I updated the question. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This loop has time complexity `O(N*M)` (using `*` to denote multiplication).

`N` is the number of items in your list, `M` is either the average value for your numbers, or the maximum possible value. Both would yield the same order, so use whichever is easier.

That arises because the number of times `...` runs is proportional to both `N` and `M`. It also assumes `...` to be constant complexity. If not you need to multiply by the complexity of `...`.

Answer (score 0):

It is `O(sum(nums[i]) * nums.size())`